# Class Inherited from ZeroDivisionError and used it in try-except block. except block is not executed

Tags: python, class, inheritance

I have a class `MyType` which is inherited from `ZeroDivisionError` class.

When I run below code `except` block is not executed. Can some one please explain why?

```
class MyType(ZeroDivisionError):
    pass

try:
    print('Inside try')
    print(5/0)
except MyType:
    print('Inside except')
```

Comment: ZeroDivisionError gets thrown instead

Comment: Yes. But why it is not printing 'Inside except' from except block?

Comment: Because it isn't throwing a `MyType` exception.

Comment: because it doesn't actually throw a MyType error. You would need to implement logic to actually throw this error, it doens't magically throw itself just because you inherit from ZeroDivisionError

Answer (score 1):

Because it doesn't actually throw a MyType error. You would need to implement logic to actually throw this error, it doens't magically throw itself just because you inherit from ZeroDivisionError

```py
class MyType(ZeroDivisionError):
    pass

try:
    print('Inside first try')
    print(5/0)
except ZeroDivisionError:
    print('Inside 1st except')
    try:
        print('Inside second try')
        raise(MyType)
    except MyType:
        print('Inside 2nd except')
```